# Swift Array with Only Two Possible Values

Tags: arrays, swift, multivalue

I want to create an array, let's say called `nums` and I want this array to hold either a `Double` or an `Error` value, and nothing else. Currently, I can get around the problem by instantiating `nums` as follows:

`var nums = Array<(Double?, Error?)>()`

Then I go through and do something like:

```
nums.append((5.0, nil))
nums.append((nil, Error.invalidNumber))
nums.append((10.0, nil))
```

This works, but instead of having `nums` have either a `Double` or an `Error` like I want, it has a tuple of those values. How can I change the instantiation of the array so that I only need to append one of the values to the array?

My goal is to be able to do this:

```
nums.append(5.0)
nums.append(Error.invalidNumber)
nums.append(10.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Result` if the type for your needs. It is a generic `enum` whose value can either be `success(Value)` (where `Value` is `Double` for your case)  or `failure(Error)`.

```
var nums = [Result<Double, Error>]()
```

And then you can do:

```
nums.append(.success(5.0))
nums.append(.failure(Error.invalidNumber))
nums.append(.success(10.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not a tuple but an enum:

```
enum DoubleOrNothing {
    case double(Double)
    case nothing(Error)
}
```

Now it can only be one or the other and the "value" is the associated value of the case that it is. Just make an array of that enum and you're home free.

```
enum MyError : Error {
    case invalidNumber
}

var nums = Array<DoubleOrNothing>()
nums.append(.double(5.0))
nums.append(.nothing(MyError.invalidNumber))
nums.append(.double(10.0))
```

Comment: Of course you will also need to learn how to _extract_ the associated value, but that isn't difficult.

Comment: I’m not sure why this was downvoted. I really wish down-voters would explain their rationale...

Comment: @Rob Some of us have Enemies... :)